# How to reload nginx in windows

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have installed nginx as a load balancer on my Windows machine using nssm. Now, I want to reload the configuration file of nginx for that I used nginx -s reload command but it is not working. It gives errors as access  denied and I don't want to restart nginx.  Is there any way to reload the nginx configuration file in windows.

Answer (score 0):

After https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,238513:

run nginx service as an admin and issue reload command from admin prompt as well

dirty way but working one

Answer (score -1):

Try following:

> nssm restart nginx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: really need answer for this. can't create new thread because it will result in duplicate question. someone/admin please drop this

Comment: nssm restart is NOT the same as NginX's  internal reload. Restart kills the process along with network connections and everything else NginX is doing. That's why NginX has Reload function, when it just reloads the new configuration keeping everything else running as they should.